# Opening multiple CSV files and averaging

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am fairly new to python, and seem to be encountering problems when opening more than one CSV file. I have 10 files for each participant and 3 conditions in each file for which I have a response time for. My aim is to open these and get the average for each participant for each of the 3 conditions. So far I am able to open one file and remove the columns which tell me the condition and then the response using this code(file has other info but what I am interested in is in columns 3&6)...

```
    import csv
    f=open('filepath')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csv_f:
        print row[3:6]
```

Obviously this is just one file and I need to then do it for them all and separate the conditions to average rt for each one! Any tips would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: you can store the data from each file in a pandas dataframe `df = pd.read_csv(filename)` you can even concatenate them `df_master = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])`, then process them however you want

Comment: Not quite sure what your data looks like, or how you intend to average?  Are you averaging the 3 vals in the file? Or the 30 vals for each participant?  The following code may help you to the next step- have a look at it, and I can update once I have a better idea of where you are going with this.

Comment: you need a list of filenames (if they follow a standard, then `glob.glob()` may be a good way to get it) and an outer `for` loop to process those files. Then you need a variable or table where you aggregate the data. Take a stab at it and ask other questions as needed.

Comment: Hi yeah sorry, my aim is to average the RT for the 3 conditions for each person, as they will be reacting to each condition multiple times in one trial! And print the participant no and mean for each condition.

Answer (score 0):

printing row[3:6] prints the vals from index 3, 4 and 5- these are the three values you want?  not sure exactly what the dataset looks like, but this may be useful to you?

```
import easygui
import csv

msg='File Processing'
title='Select folder of csv files'
process_dir = easygui.fileopenbox()

def f_processor(f):
    fh=open(f)
    csv_f = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in csv_f:
        print row[3:6]

for filename in process_dir:
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        f_processor(filename)
    else:
        print("Not a csv file")
```